How to use "to a greater extent" properly when comparing the increases of two figures



Types of vehicles
2010
2014
% change (from 2010 to 2014)




passenger vehicles
11.8
13
10.2%


commercial vehicles
2.3
2.7
17.4%



The first sentence is where I commented on how the number of passenger vehicles increased, then I proceeded to write the following one:

"...A similar change, but to a greater extent, can be seen in the figure for commercial vehicles, which climbed by 17.4% from 2.3 million in 2010 to 2.7 million in 2014."

By "to a greater extent", I mean increased by a greater percentage. But is it correct considering the fact that  passenger vehicles increased by a greater number?

I think if you change the criteria from “increase in numbers” to “percentage rise”, you open yourself to confusion. Always try to compare like with like when using “greater extent”.
To have an “extent” of anything, you must know to which measurement that refers. When using “greater extent” it is advisable, if not imperative that the same measurement is being referred to.

Are you suggesting that I shouldn't use the phrase "to a greater extent" at all if I want to compare both the percentages and the numbers in the same sentence?

In general, yes. It just aids clarity. If you say something used to be 15% but it’s now larger at 200, it gives no real information about how much larger that is.
